# when the constructor is called?

Tags: c++, constructor, global

Suppose we have a class in C++

```
class X {
    int i;
public:
    X(int y): i(y) {}
};

X r(10);

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

So we have an global object r.
My question is that when the constructor for global or static objects is been called, at compile-time or at runtime? Because the execution of the program starts at the main function.
And till then all the global objects should be intitialized.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor and one in main and find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly not at compile time. It's called at run-time, before `main` enters. All globals and statics (excluding method scoped statics) are initialized then.

Comment: But the execution starts at the main() so how could then they be initialized before entering main?

Comment: @Luv no it doesn't. `main` is the entry point, it's called by the run-time. But it's not the first thing that gets called.